# rotating an image inside a gameloop when moving with arrow key int html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/B2nUs/6/

for instance i am trying to move up and left as you can see the rotation function that i am using is not working.What i am trying to do is when i move to the left the tank image rotate to the left and start moving normally to the left by decrementing `x` coordinate  can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code and why this weird behavior is occurring  ?

```
    draw: function () {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.translate(this.x + 28, this.y + 28);
    var angleInRadians = this.rotation * Math.PI / 180;
    ctx.rotate(angleInRadians);
    ctx.drawImage(tankImg, this.Pos * this.w, 0, this.w, this.h, this.x, this.y, this.w / 3, this.h / 3);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drawImage you need to adjust for half the desired image width/height because you've already translated to where you want the center of the image to be:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.translate(x + 28, y + 28);
var angleInRadians = rotation * Math.PI / 180;
ctx.rotate(angleInRadians);
ctx.drawImage(tankImg, Pos*w,0, w,h, -w/6,-h/6, w/3,h/3 );
ctx.restore();
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/CLe8Z/